# running instance of a hello world node app in docker but unable to reach on port 8080

Tags: node.js, docker, server

I have a simple webserver listener which is running fine in docker with the command

```
docker build -t node-hello-world:latest .
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name node-hello-world node-hello-world:latest
```

here's the app:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express')
const app = express();

const port = 8080;
const host = '0.0.0.0';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World from IBM Cloud Essentials!');
})

app.listen(port, host);
console.log(`Running on http://${host}:${port}`);
```

the first log entry is outputting fine: `Running on http://${host}:${port}`

but trying `localhost:8080` just says "This site can’t be reached".  Here is my `docker ps -a` code:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
0995c28fabed   node-hello-world:latest               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                                                                                                                 node-hello-world
```

Comment: That setup looks fine; you have the right `docker run -p` option and you're listening on `0.0.0.0`, which are the two important things I'd check.  Where are you calling that URL from?  What is your host OS and Docker installation?

Answer (score 0):

This article might help:

> https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14114/how-to-connect-to-localhost-within-a-docker-container/
>
> Docker Desktop 18.03+ for Windows and Mac supports
> `host.docker.internal` as a functioning alias for localhost. Use this
> string inside your containers to access your host machine.
>
> - localhost and 127.0.0.1 – These resolve to the container.
> - host.docker.internal – This resolves to the outside host.'

Additionally,

> Docker provides a host network which lets containers share your host’s
> networking stack. This approach means localhost inside a container
> resolves to the physical host, instead of the container itself.
>
> Containers are launched with the host network by adding the `--network=host` flag:
>
> ```
> docker run -d --network=host my-container:latest
> ```
>
> Now your container can reference localhost or 127.0.0.1 directly.
>
> If you’re using Docker Compose, modify your container’s service
> definition to include the network_mode field:
>
> ```
> services:
>   my-service:
>     network_mode: host
> ```

See also: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-machine